# How to avoid problems with static method in @BeforeClass

Tags: java, junit

I have a JUnit test class, in which I create a `TemporaryFolder` and test my program in this directory with newly created files and folders. Currently, everything is set up at `@Before` event:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();
File testFile1;
File testFile2;
public List<String> folderItems = new ArrayList<>();

@Before
public void initalise() throws IOException {
    testFile1 = folder.newFile("test1.txt");
    testFile2 = folder.newFile("test2.txt");
    folderItems.add(testFile1.getName());
    folderItems.add(testFile2.getName());
    Directory.setCurrentDirectory(folder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath());
}
```

However, I read that `@Before` is executed before each test and since my tests will all be using the same folder structure, it is better to use `@BeforeClass` which is only executed once. Here, however, I have an issue with the fact that the method needs to be static. That yields error because then all the variables would need to be static. However, the list can't be static as I am adding the `testFiles` name into it during initialization.
Any idea how to solve this?

**EDIT**
I have changed the file into this:

```
@ClassRule
public static TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();
public static File testFile1;
public static File testFile2;
public static List<String> folderItems;


@BeforeClass
public static void setUpFolder() {
    try {
        testFile1 = folder.newFile("test1.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        testFile2 = folder.newFile("test2.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }
    folderItems.add(testFile1.getName());
    folderItems.add(testFile2.getName());
 Directory.setCurrentDirectory(folder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Despite this not throwing any errors, my test doesn't actually get executed and passed, I receive and `initializationError`
[image]

Comment: Obviously, you need to make the fields static (and use `@ClassRule`), if you want them to apply for all tests.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for your comment, please see the edit

Comment: If you get an error when doing this, then please post the exception stacktrace.